# Regex doesn't respect the length limits

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex in Java for matching with the user's name:

```
^(?!.*\\..*\\..*)[A-Za-z]([A-Za-z0-9.]*[A-Za-z0-9]){8,15}$
```

I expect this regex to match with strings that contains all alphanumeric character (starts with alphabet), with at most one period (dot) allowed in the middle and size between 8 and 15.

Hence, it has two issues:

1. It doesn't accept strings of length 8. It accepts string with minimum length of 9.
2. There is no upper boundary for the length. It matches with any string longer than 8 characters.

Why doesn't it take into account the `{8,15}`?

Comment: Please give some examples to be accepted

Comment: You should add it as an answer @bobblebubble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue 1**: You're quantifying the group that requires at least one `[A-Za-z0-9]` with any amount of `[A-Za-z0-9.]` before. Hence already requires at least 8 characters. Plus your regex requires an `[A-Za-z]` before this construct = 9 characters at least.

**Issue 2**: You're quantifying a group that contains `[A-Za-z0-9.]*` any amount and this `{8,15}` so the upper limit is 15x(any amount) = ∞

Guess the regex you're after would look similar this one:

```
^(?![^.]*\\.[^.]*\\.)[A-Za-z](?:\\.?[A-Za-z0-9]){7,14}$
```

[See demo and more explanation at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aeofZm/3)